# Volunteer on Boat from Israel to Europe

Tags: israel, sea-travel, volunteering

I would like to travel from Israel to Europe by boat (specifically I want to get to Holland, but anywhere in Europe will do).

It seems there are no longer passenger boats going from Israel to Cyprus/Greece or any other place. In any case, I heard about opportunities to travel by sailing boat or cargo ship while volunteering. For example, a boat owner wants his boat transported from A to B, and so a few people can volunteer bringing the boat there, traveling for free.

Does anyone know more about this?
I checked out crewseekers and workaway but couldn't find any boats departing from Israel.
By the way, I have hardly any sailing experience (but heard they need also people without experience)

Comment: Probably easier thought than done. On a modern cargo ship there's not many useful tasks to do that an untrained landlubber _can_ do, without costing the existing crew as much time in instruction and supervision as they save doing the actual work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voluntering on board of a cargo ship can be hard as Henning wrote in a comment. On some cargo ships however once can rent a passage. I for instance found this German prospectus with a ship touching Haifa: https://frachtschiffreisen-pfeiffer.de/reisedateien/programm/Pfeiffer-Programm-Suedeuropa.pdf (2nd entry on page 4)  If one can join in Haifa or only Hamburg I don't know, you might send them a message. With cargo ships however mind that the routes can change while traveling depending on business needs. Cargo has way higher precedence over passengers.

Volunteering can be simpler on sailing yachts. [Find a Crew](https://www.findacrew.net/en/boat/search?action=Results&BtSrt=_LLD&QckAvl=NF&str_LocSrh_Fmt=Haifa%2C%20Israel&real_LocSrh_Lat=32.7940463&real_LocSrh_Lng=34.98957100000007&LocDis=463000) is a site collecting such offers. Typically however skippers prefer to have people for the complete turn and those are smaller boats, thus it's more likely to become seasick.